# Hardware (/fakeraid?) RAID 1 fails to show correct size using Asus X99-PRO

Tags: partitioning, raid, asus, dmraid

I have a Ubuntu-only system with 3 disks, 1 SSD drive and 2 identical mechanical drives. The first one has the core Ubuntu install while the latter 2 I want to set-up with RAID 1. Unfortunately I get all kinds of errors when trying to set-up the system, currently `parted` complains about volume integrity and the mapped volume is only a fragment of the drive size.

My original thought was that the RAID 1 drive would simply turn up as a single drive but it currently I see both drive + a smaller RAID-mapper (not sure how to interpret this):

```
my_comp:~$ sudo lsblk -o NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL
NAME                                FSTYPE   SIZE MOUNTPOINT LABEL
sda                                          477G            
├─sda1                              ext4     413G /          
├─sda2                                         1K            
└─sda5                                      63,9G            
sdb                                          2,7T            
└─isw_beebgfifaf_Volume1 (dm-0)            746,5G            
  └─isw_beebgfifaf_Volume1p1 (dm-1)          128M            
sdc                                          2,7T            
└─isw_beebgfifaf_Volume1 (dm-0)            746,5G            
  └─isw_beebgfifaf_Volume1p1 (dm-1)          128M
```

Doing a list with parted show some Microsoft volumes and also crashes on the mapped volume:

```
my_comp:~$ sudo parted -l /dev/sdb
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 850 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 512GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos

Number  Start   End    Size    Type      File system  Flags
 1      1049kB  443GB  443GB   primary   ext4         boot
 2      443GB   512GB  68,6GB  extended
 5      443GB   512GB  68,6GB  logical


Model: ATA WDC WD3003FZEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdb: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17,4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   3001GB  3000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Model: ATA WDC WD3003FZEX-0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sdc: 3001GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      17,4kB  134MB   134MB                Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 2      135MB   3001GB  3000GB  ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata


Error: /dev/mapper/isw_beebgfifaf_Volume1p1: unrecognised disk label      

Error: Invalid argument during seek for read on                           
/dev/mapper/isw_beebgfifaf_Volume1
```

**Question**: How do I correctly set-up the 2,7Tb hardware RAID-configuration in Ubuntu?

The Asus X99-PRO card seems to be powered by [*Intel® Rapid Storage Technology*](http://dlcdnet.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/X99-PRO/e9707_x99-pro_ug_for_web_only.pdf) - is this [fakeraid](https://askubuntu.com/questions/397040/hardware-raid-1-problems) and does this require a different approach (I already have the dmraid-package installed)?