# Hardware RAID1 not recognized

Tags: hard-drive, dell, raid

I have a Dell Precision 7820 running Ubuntu 20.04.06, for which I have setup a hardware RAID1 with two 20TB HDDs:
[image]

When I check Disks, I cannot see it as a single RAID1 volume, but only as two separate drives:
[image]

I have checked the Dell website but I could not find any additional information or drivers.
How can I properly setup this RAID1 volume in Ubuntu?

Comment: It could be that your bios uses a fake RAID. Which means that it is a software RAID under the hood. This works with windows but not with linux. You can use `dmraid` to fix this issue. See this answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/397074/927593